# Want to get rid of null values with known values from other rows

Tags: sql, select, null, case

I have a list of logs in a database.  Each log is associated with a person.  Each person is Associated with a group.  However, some of the group fields are NULL for whatever reason.

I would like to use the known group values from other rows for these people and replace the NULL values using a CASE in a Select Statement (open to other ideas just not update or create table ;) )

I.E.

```
ID    NAME    GROUP  
====================  
1     ALex     NULL     
2     Amanda   San Antonio    
3     Alex     Austin
4     John     Toronto
```

What I would like is

```
ID    NAME    GROUP  
====================  
1     Alex     Austin
2     Amanda   San Antonio    
3     Alex     Austin
4     John     Toronto
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is ANSI syntax for doing this:

```
update t
    set "group" = (select max("group") from t t2 where t2.name = t.name)
    where "group" is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [Group] = g.[Group]
FROM Table1 t INNER JOIN (
SELECT [Name], [Group]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Group] IS NOT NULL
  ) g ON t.Name = g.Name
WHERE t.[Group] IS NULL
```

Have a look at this demo

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6319/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
Update NLGS
Set NLGS.Group =LGS.Group 
FROM 
Logs NLGS
INNER JOIn 
(select Name,Group from logs
 WHER GROUp is not null) LGS
ON NLGS.Name=LGS.NAME
WHERE NLGS.GROUP IS NULL
```

In this the assumption is there is only one combination of not null group and name. other wise it results in 1-many join.Which can be corrected based on your selection criterion.